# StartMenuExperienceHost.exe keeps waking my computer

Tags: windows-10, wake-up

Did anybody find a solution for this? I have tried all posted answers to similar topics and could stop most of the issues that were causing windows to return from hibernation except this last one. I'm running Windows 10 Pro, latest update.

Comment: Apparently [this](https://blog.hqcodeshop.fi/archives/459-Windows-10-May-2019-update-1903-breaking-sleep.html) is the solution and was suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/1414945/345617) as well, but I can't confirm at the moment. In general, apps [can](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/why-does-power-options-sleep-allow-wake-timers/4bf24b81-c4bc-4c42-89a2-f252f509ef60) bypass the power plan settings and still set wakeup timers. The MS ones may be better behaved and honor that Group policy, but I suspect other apps might not be so nice.